# Why doesn't swift allow me to create a protocol type field?

Tags: swift, generics, memory, swift-protocols, swift-structs

As I know, structure is a value type and it stores all it's fields nearby in a continuous memory segment, the size of which should be known at the time of compilation. So, as I think, because of the constant size of the reference to some object, there shouldn't be a problem to compile this code:

```
struct Some {
    weak var delegate: SomeDelegate?
}

protocol SomeDelegate {
    ...some functions...
}
```

So struct 'Some' will have only one field with 32 or 64 bit size(how I think it should be). But swift compiler issues an error to this lines and says:

"'weak' must not be applied to non-class-bound 'any SomeDelegate'; consider adding a protocol conformance that has a class bound"
Of course I can do this task with generics or associated types, but why "'weak' must not be applied to non-class-bound 'any SomeDelegate'"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `weak` with protocols if you make your protocol conform to `AnyObject`

```
struct Some {
    weak var delegate: (any SomeDelegate)?
}

protocol SomeDelegate: AnyObject {
    ...
}
```

Weak (reference) can only be used with reference types. Structs and enums are value types, classes are reference types.

This is why the protocol must be a class-only (`AnyObject`) protocol